# Powershell Nested Hashtables - Export to file

Tags: powershell, object, collections, export

Im pulling out information from AD to output alot of information to be handled at a later point.

I need to export this to a csv or something so i can have a rollback ( in effect import file so i can handle each object like i can with the hashtable below. Especially that inside $_.MemberOf).

The hashtable im struggling with handling is:

```
$logging1 = @{
MemberOf="$users.MemberOf"
OriginalOU="$Ou.DistinguishedName"
DisabledWhen="$descriptionDisabled"
}
$logging = @{$users.SamAccountname = $logging1}
```

what the rest of the script does is(that isnt pasted ) is:

iterate through a bunch of ou's. Getting users last logged in -90 days ago or more then passing them to the HashTable in question which i like to append to a file to be imported at a later time.

I have been googling for hours without getting somewhere

here is the complete script:

```
import-module ActiveDirectory
$descriptionDisabled = get-date -Format yyyyMMdd
$Loggdir = "C:\temp"
$array = @{}
$loggname = get-date -f yyyyMMdd
$90days = ((get-date).AddDays(-90))
$searchBase = 'OU=someou4,OU=someou3,OU=someou2,OU=someou1,DC=name,DC=NO'
$ExclusionList = Someexlutions
$OUlist = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase $searchBase 
foreach ($Ou in $OUlist)
{
$ExpiredADusers = get-aduser -Filter {(LastlogonDate -le $90days) 
                                      -and (Enabled -eq $True)}
                             -SearchBase $ou.distinguishedname
                             -Properties * 
#Get information about every user and their groupmembership
foreach ($Users in $ExpiredADusers)
    {
    $users = get-aduser -Identity $users.SamAccountName
                        -Properties * 
             | Select-Object -Property SamAccountName, MemberOf, 
                                       DistinguishedName, ObjectGUID
    $logging =  @{$person.SamAccountName = @{
    MemberOf=$person.MemberOf;
    OriginalOU=$Ou.DistinguishedName;
    DisabledWhen="$descriptionDisabled"}}
    $Array += $Logging   

    }         
}

$array | export-clixml -path somepath -noclobber
```

**EDIT SOLVED**
Solved problem and original script in question has been updated to handle Nested hashtables

**Original problem**
I think you can understand what im trying to do.
Im making a rollback file incase needed.

So the exported file need to be easy to import. when using hashtables you can use . notations and each objects under memberof is treated as an object

What the rollback needs is so i can iterate through the imported info to move the user back to its original OU placement and restore membership

Comment: Export the object using Export-CLIXml then import it using Import-CLIXml if you need it back.

Comment: There is no option for Appending to CLIXml

Im also having trouble with adding the user data to the hashtable

using $logging += @{$users.SamAccountname = $logging1}
doesnt work. How to i append users into that hashtable?

Also i can see when i import the xml again the objects in Memberof is not treated as strings. So im not sure how to get then to handle as objects again.

Comment: I'm not positive that I understand everything that you are trying to do but I think if I were in your shoes at this point I would look at creating a custom object for each user and putting the proerties on the object that you need for later then put all those into a single array. Then you could export to a CSV (which does allow you to append.

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to understand and point me in the right direction. Se the answer given to TheMadTechnician.

Im so new to this so everything helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think EBGreen really hit the nail on the head here. You need an array of custom objects, and then you can just export it to a CSV like you want to. It's a really minor change in code too.

```
$Array = @()
$ForEach($User in $Users){
    $logging1 = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        MemberOf=$user.MemberOf
        OriginalOU=$Ou.DistinguishedName
        DisabledWhen=$descriptionDisabled
    }
    $Array += $Logging1

}
```

**Edit:** Hm, so you want to be able to export and import full objects. You don't want a CSV then because you have nested arrays, and a CSV is not designed to handle that for export and import. You need XML, so, as mentioned above, you need to use Export-Clixml and Import-Clixml since XML can handle nested arrays. Just pipe the array to it once the array has all your data and you should be all set.

**Edit2:** The hashtables within hashtables issue... Ok, so we had it as `MemberOf="$user.MemberOf"` and that's the issue. It is converting it to a string, so it is expanding the entire $`User` variable, and tacking `.MemberOf` to the end of it. We don't really want to do it in this case, but if you want to access a property of an object from within doublequotes you need to put `$()` around it. For example if you wanted to include the user's distinguishedname as a part of human friendly output you could do something like:

```
Write-Output "$($Users.Name)'s distinguished name is: $($users.distinguishedname)"
```

Which would output something like:

```
TMTech's distinguished name is: CN=TMTech,OU=Awesome,OU=Administrators,DC=Digital,DC=Ghost,DC=net
```

Comment: Se the full script in the edit. That should explain what im trying to achieve. i want it to be as easy as using dot notation as you can in a nested hashtable.
where each object in memberof can be treated seperatly

Btw im really new to powershell and trying my best to understand it.
the exporting section is not my strongest side when i need to import it also and handle the info as objects

I really appreciate all the help i can get. And im not asking to write me full codes. I've come a long way and as long as i can grasp the export and import fully it will become much simpler for me.

Thanks

Comment: Updated answer to handle your needs.

Comment: here is info shown in $array: @{SamAccountName=et2316; Member... OU=Someou,OU=Someou,DC=... 20140429 @{SamAccountName=et2316; Member...

 What is wrong in my script. I the way it adds to the array?

Comment: Here is what $array[0].memberof  is showing:

@{SamAccountName=sete; MemberOf=Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection; DistinguishedName=CN=Name,OU=someou,OU=Admin Users,DC=Dc,DC=NO; ObjectGUID=6baac39f-8219-407e-b08b-1f1266939499}.MemberOf

Comment: The answer is simple. Remove the quotes. `Username=$users.SamAccountName` is how the properties should read.

Comment: Thank you so much. I used the nested array @{$user.samaccountname = @{Memberof=User.memberof;
OU=OU.DistinguishedName}}

and added it to $array which is defined as $array = @{}

Pipes the $array variable to xml with -noclobber

Importing the xml now dows EXACTLY what i wanted :) 

Thank you so very much for helping me out.
Im still not that good at exporting info but this is a stepcloser to working more with hashtables

Comment: I also updated my answer to explain the whole double quotes issue. If this resolved you question please mark the answer as accepted to help future users with similar questions.

Comment: You made it much easier to understand :) Thank you for lending me you time to answer this. Much appreciated. I will mark it as accepted as this helped me a long way to handle the info in case of roll back

Comment: Updating the original script for those having the same problem can use this as guide